# remove an object from observable array in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to remove an object from an observable array, but I give up.

I use knockout.js and devextreme.

How can I remove an object from the array?

the **javascript**

```
    CaptionViewOptions: {
        items: self.FunctionsList,
        showCheckBoxesMode: true,
        height: 400,
        searchValue: self.searCachInput,
        parentIdExpr: "ID",
        keyExpr: "ID",
        displayExpr: "ControlCaption",

        onItemSelectionChanged:
           function (s) {

               self.selfID();
               self.Control();
               self.selfID(s.itemData.ID);
               self.Control(s.itemData.Control);

               if (s.itemData.selected === true) {

                var item = {selfID:self.selfID() ,Control:self.Control() }
                self.SelectedFunction.push(item);


               }
               else {
                   var itemstodelete = { selfID: self.selfID(), Control: self.ControlCaption() };
                   SelectedFunction.remove(itemstodelete);

               }
           }
```

the **html**

```
 <div data-bind="dxTextBox:vm.SubViewModel.CaptionSearchOptions"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you give up? I think you mean you are trying hard but just need a little help?

Comment: How is the problem manifesting itself? Where are you facing trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SelectedFunction` is an array, the value you're trying to remove doesn't exist in the array because you're creating a brand new object. Even though the values within the object are the same as one that exists it's not the same object, and will never be "equal" to the one in the array.

See: [Object equality in javascript](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html)

You'll have to change your code to search for the existing object by comparing the values manually.

```
...
else {
    //var itemstodelete = { selfID: self.selfID(), Control: self.ControlCaption() };
    for(var i=0; i<SelectedFunction.length; i++){
        if(SelectedFunction[i].selfID === self.selfID() && SelectedFunction[i].Control === self.ControlCaption()){
            SelectedFunction.remove(SelectedFunction[i]); //this can be rewritten to remove via the index to be more efficient
        }
    }
}
```